# Help me finding nth derivative

Tags: derivatives

I am beginning in Successive Differentiation. This is a very simple question in differentiation, but I am confused.

Find a closed formula for the $n^{\text{th}}$ derivative of:

$$\frac {x^2}{(x+2)(2x+3)}$$

Edit: Denominator updated

Comment: I think this needs clarification.  Are you just after the first derivative?  What goes wrong when you use the standard properties of the derivative?  Or are you after a simple form for the $n^{th}$ derivative?

Comment: @lulu I need to form general form for nth derivative.

Comment: Have you tried partial fractions before successive differentiations?

Comment: Note:  the partial fractions hint works just as well even after the changes you made.

Comment: @jbuddenh you made my day. Thanks !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [Partial Fraction Decomposition](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartialFractionDecomposition.html),
 let $$\frac {x^2}{(x+2)(2x+3)}=A+\dfrac B{x+2}+\dfrac C{2x+3}$$

Comment: See http://learnmathforfree.jimdo.com/calculus/nth-derivative/

Answer (score 1):

HINT: we have $$\frac{x^2}{(x+2)(x+3)}=\frac{x^2}{x^2+5x+6}$$ after the quotient rule we obtain
$$\frac{2x(x^2+5x+6)-x^2(2x+5)}{(x^2+5x+6)^2}$$ after the update we have 
$$\frac{2x(2x^2+7x+6)-x^2(4x+7)}{(2x^2+7x+6)^2}$$
itis better to use this form
$$1/2-4\, \left( x+2 \right) ^{-1}+9/2\, \left( 2\,x+3 \right) ^{-1}$$
for the first derivative you will get
$$4\, \left( x+2 \right) ^{-2}-9\, \left( 2\,x+3 \right) ^{-2}$$
the next derivative is given by $$-8\, \left( x+2 \right) ^{-3}+36\, \left( 2\,x+3 \right) ^{-3}$$

Comment: The question asks for the $n$-th derivative, not just the first. This approach doesn't really help.

Comment: which can be simplified to $${\frac {x \left( 7\,x+12 \right) }{ \left( x+2 \right) ^{2} \left( 2\,
x+3 \right) ^{2}}}
$$

Comment: from where do you know this?

Comment: From the title of the question, the discussion in the comments, and the most recent clarifying edit.

Comment: Your recent edit helps